# AutoUpdater.NET not updating and not removing old program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, auto-update

I'm using [AutoUpdater](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET) alongside Visual Studio Installer Projects in a WPF program. When updating my project, it never actually updates. It only gives the option to "Repair" or "Remove" my existing installation. This causes the program to always ask for updates (since it's still on the old version, 1.0.0.0).

My update code (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
AutoUpdater.Start(@"\\SERVER\foo\bar\update.xml", new NetworkCredential("user", "pass"));
AutoUpdater.ShowSkipButton = false;
AutoUpdater.Synchronous = true;
AutoUpdater.Mandatory = true;
AutoUpdater.UpdateMode = Mode.Forced;
```

My update.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<item>
  <version>1.0.1.2</version>
  <url>\\SERVER\foo\bar\setup.msi</url>
  <mandatory>true</mandatory>
</item>
```

My Deployment Project settings:

```
DetectNewerInstalledVersion = False
RemovePreviousVersions = True
Version = 1.0.1.2
```

My AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.2")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1.2")]
```

I change the setup version (which generates a new ProductCode) to match the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion.
However when it goes to update, it only gives the option to Repair or Remove the current installation. Continuing with "Repair" does not actually Update the program. The next time you start the program, it is still on the old version and will ask to update again.

The UpgradeCode remains the same. Setting DetectNewerInstalledVersion to true causes Windows to throw the error "An older version is already installed" but I am trying to eliminate the user from having to uninstall and re-install for each update.

[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

lblVersion.Text = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

```
        AutoUpdater.DownloadPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\UpdateExtrator\\";
        //AutoUpdater.InstallationPath = Application.StartupPath;

        AutoUpdater.CheckForUpdateEvent += AutoUpdaterOnCheckForUpdateEvent;         
        AutoUpdater.ReportErrors = true;
        AutoUpdater.UpdateMode = Mode.Forced;
        AutoUpdater.RunUpdateAsAdmin = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not compress the installer , compress the contents of your release or debug folder these must be the files for installation in zip format

https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET/issues/213